# Is there a way to turn off naming suggestions in a code snippet?

Tags: autocomplete, visual-studio-code

I'm writing Selenium page object classes in Java in Visual Studio Code.  I created a custom code snippet that, when entered, looks more or less like this:

```
public WebElement ELEMENTNAME() {
    return driver.findElementByCssSelector("CSSSELECTOR");
}
```

After I enter the snippet name and hit Tab, ELEMENTNAME gets the focus.  I type the element name I've picked, such as `ConfirmButton`, and hit Tab...whereupon I find that my method now has the name `ConfirmButtonElement`, because VS Code decided to accept its own naming suggestion instead of what I typed.

How can I turn this "feature" off?

Usually VS Code's autocomplete suggestions are helpful, so I don't want to disable them entirely.  But I definitely want to disable them in the case of naming things.  Is there a way to do that?

(I'm not sure whether the behavior comes from VS Code itself or from an extension such as the Red Hat Java extensions.)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Extension to blame:** It is actually happening because of [Microsoft Java Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack). Though it also includes the Red Hat Java Package

**2. To disable this package:** You can navigate to Extensions tab in VScode and search for Microsoft Java Extension Pack and click disable package.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when this may have been added to vscode, but have a look at:

> // Control whether an active snippet prevents quick suggestions.

```
  "editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": true,
```

`true` is the default, try `false`.